# If H is Hermitian why does $H=H^T$ in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

**From Hobson, Bence, Riley-Mathematical methods pg 290**
Given the Hermitian form $H(x)\equiv x^\dagger Ax$ and A is Hermitian the proof writer is claiming/proving that H is real (when x can be imaginary and $A^\dagger=A$, *=complex conjugate, and $\dagger=$Hermitian.
The proof is one line:
$$H^*=(\color{red}{H^T})^*=x^\dagger A^\dagger x=x^\dagger Ax=H$$
Why does $H=H^T$?

I believe $H^T=x^T A^* x^*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because $H$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix....

Comment: Aha! good one!! I can't accept for 6 more minutes.

Comment: @user135711 that's okay. Actually I was thinking about it for quite a while (following the explicit expression of $H^T$ in your post), before I suddenly realised $H$ is a scalar.